# $_POST['hidd'] != '20' doesnt work correctly

Tags: php

I simply  want to execute some codes in this "if":
`if ($_POST['hidd'] != '20')`
$_POST works correctly.
but the problem is in `!= '20'`.
how can i make it works?

Comment: add another `=` or remove the quotes for the integer or both ?

Comment: How exactly does it fail? "Doesn't work" is not a problem description. What do you *expect* it to do and what *does* it do?

Comment: what does print_r($_POST) output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['hidd']) && $_POST['hidd'] != '20') {
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
if ($_POST['hidd'] != 20){
// code here
}
```

do you put `if(isset($_POST['hidd']))` at top of your code?

Comment: I'm not sure you can understand OP's question with current elements. You're just blind-guessing. I'm not sure it's fine for us.

Comment: sorry. i forget to put '!'. thanks for your remind.